# 'apply on' or 'apply to'

Tags: word-choice

I have a new approach and data and I want to apply this new approach **on** a set of data.
But a friend of mine says I have to a apply it **to** the data. So in

> We apply this novel approach X the naninani corpus.

is it **on** or **to**?

Comment: Both are correct; depending on context and the intended meaning, one of them is used. There's a subtle different in usage of the two prepositions. In the given example, *to* is adequate and fits well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking forward to reading the interpretations of others here.  Straight up, I would say that it's:

> We apply this novel approach **to** the naninani corpus.

Not to say that the other is incorrect, but because - and it's just opinion here - *apply to* is pretty much a phrasal verb.

Looking only at the preposition *[to](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to?s=t)*, however, it indicates movement towards a destination. It's not entirely analogous to actually reaching that destination.  Well, not without further information. You can apply to university, but that doesn't mean you get accepted.

The preposition *[on](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on?s=t)* conveys something different, it implies a connection has been made, whether that be physical or abstract.  Take waxing a car; you can apply wax to a car, no problem, but really you're applying wax *on* the car. Or *onto* the car, if you prefer.

Coming back to your question, the choice will be dependent on your focus. I still feel that

> We apply this novel approach **to** the naninani corpus.

is more fitting. It covers a broader interpretation, and it's less of a sticking point for readers. If you want to focus more on the results of the application you could consider using

> We apply this novel approach **on** the naninani corpus.

and then get stuck into those results.